# Using search function in rails to retrieve a result and display it first in the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, view

I am trying to implement search functionality in my rails app where I search and display a particular search result first on my index.html.erb view. At the moment I have a search function working and it returns the particular item on its own on the index page.

Ideally I would like to have this item displayed first and then all the other items to display below.

My code is as follows:

brand.rb

```
 def self.search(query)
    where("author like ?", "%#{query}%")
  end
```

brand_controller.rb

```
      def index
    if params[:search]
      @brand = Brand.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @brand = Brand.all.order(':date')
    end
  end
```

I know the where method returns the value as an array so I could probably use array.first to output this result first but is there an easier way to output my desired view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So turned out to be a pretty simple solution, I blame mondays.

All I had to do was create another variable for my search and iterate that result first, then iterate through the rest of the items.

in my controller

```
 def index
      @brand = Brand.order('created_at DESC')
      if params[:search]
        @brand = Brand.search(params[:search]).order("author DESC")
        @other = Brand.search_all(params[:search]).order("author DESC")
      else
        @brand = Brand.all.order('author DESC')
      end
  end
```

In my model

```
  def self.search(query)
      where("author like ?", "%#{query}%")
  end

  def self.search_all(query)
    where("author not like ?", "%#{query}%")
  end
```

and finally in my view

```
 <% if @brand.any? %>

                      <% @brand.in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>
                          <% group.each do |brand| %>
                              <% if brand %>

                                      <h4> <%= brand.author %></h4>
                                      <a href="<%=brand_path(brand)%>">
                                        <%=image_tag brand.brand_logo, class: 'img-rounded', :"data-uid" => brand.uid %>  </a>

                              <% end %>
                          <% end %>
                      <% end %>
              <% end %>





                  <% if @other %>

                      <% @other.in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>

                          <% group.each do |other| %>
                              <% if other %>
                                      <h4> <%= other.author%></h4>
                                      <a href="<%=brand_path(other)%>">
                                        <%=image_tag other.brand_logo %>  </a>
                              <% end %>
                          <% end %>
                      <% end %>
                  <% end %>
```